# A particular customize with green line and letters for subfloat

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, captions, subfloats, subcaption

For my book, the MWE that it is adding below, is the cropping of a part of the code when I insert only two figures:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book} 
\usepackage{newtxtext}
%%\usepackage{classico}%%%%%%%%% urw-classico package. The fonts are installed into my MikTeX distribuition
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[labelfont={sf,bf},skip=.3pt]{caption}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\subfloat[][\small Le linee di universo passanti per l'origine saranno all'interno del cono. Si vede la linea blu che parte dal punto qui ed ora rappresentato dal vertice del cono.]
{\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}} \quad
\subfloat[][\small  Linee di universo non ammesse nella teoria della relatività ristretta sono quelle che escono dal cono di luce; ad esempio la linea \textbf{(1)} esce dal cono che pertanto non sarà ammessa; la velocità nel punto $A$ della linea \textbf{(2)} è minore di quella della luce; la linea arancione \textbf{(3)} rappresenta un viaggiatore dello spazio-tempo con il dono dell'ubiquità; la linea \textbf{(4)} rappresenta un viaggio indietro nel tempo a una velocità maggiore di quella della luce.]
{\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
\caption{\small Coni di luce.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to recreate the same (exact) figure below the green lines with the green squares (rounded it is preferible) with into the letters?

The green line with the green square where there are the letters `a`, `b`, `c`, and the relative labels in Figure 1 (a), (b) and (c). It varies with the lenght of the images.

See here:

[image]

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've put it all in as a surprise effect for those who look as if they were wondering. Now I edit my question following your comments.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I hadn't put in the % before to turn the package into a comment. As you can see I had written a series of %%%% with the notice that the fonts are installed into my MikTeX distribution.

Comment: Sorry  I get errors but I dIdn't on a different installation, my setup is testing some future code, ignore my comments about that. I may trace later why I get errors but that is not your problem:-)

Comment: Don't worry David. For me you are always "benvenuto". In the meantime, if there are any mistakes in English and you don't understand my question, please edit it. Thank you.

Comment: for me it works in texlive 2017 but not 2018 or 2019 (but I have a non standard setup, others may confirm)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle On my TeXLive 2018 distribution it runs through when compiled with xelatex. Most likely this the is the WOW effect. ;-)

Comment: @marmot May I comment that you made me smile? :-) I never thought that on other platforms my code would make mistakes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it's just a line so

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book} 
\usepackage{newtxtext}
%%%%%\usepackage{classico}%%%%%%%%% urw-classico package. The fonts are installed into my MikTeX distribuition
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{mathtools,color}
\usepackage[labelfont={sf,bf},skip=.3pt]{caption}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\subfloat[][\small Le linee di universo passanti per l'origine saranno all'interno del cono. Si vede la linea blu che parte dal punto qui ed ora rappresentato dal vertice del cono.

\textcolor{green}{\makebox[0pt][l]{\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}}}\quad\colorbox{green}{\bfseries\color{white}{a}}
]
{\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}} \quad
\subfloat[][\small  Linee di universo non ammesse nella teoria della relatività ristretta sono quelle che escono dal cono di luce; ad esempio la linea \textbf{(1)} esce dal cono che pertanto non sarà ammessa; la velocità nel punto $A$ della linea \textbf{(2)} è minore di quella della luce; la linea arancione \textbf{(3)} rappresenta un viaggiatore dello spazio-tempo con il dono dell'ubiquità; la linea \textbf{(4)} rappresenta un viaggio indietro nel tempo a una velocità maggiore di quella della luce.

\textcolor{green}{\makebox[0pt][l]{\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}}}\quad\colorbox{green}{\bfseries\color{white}{b}}
]
{\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
\caption{\small Coni di luce.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

(I had to use texlive 2017 to get the example to run for some reason)

Comment: Very nice. But for green square do not use the symbol `\square`? But if I wanted to insert a rounded square or another symbol is it possible to have the same result?

Comment: @Sebastiano could use any symbol you want behind the letter rather than colorbox, or if you wait a bit someone is bound to suggest a tikz version with a duck shaped background or whatever other shape you want drawn.