# A new and better aesthetic look for figures and captions with vertical braces

Tags: tikz-pgf, captions, subcaption, subfig, rounded-corners

Starting for the question [Center a rounded square into a green line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481885/center-a-rounded-square-into-a-green-line) with the excellent @marmot's answer, using your MWE,

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book} 
\usepackage{newtxtext}
%%\usepackage{classico}%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[labelfont={sf,bf},font=small,skip=.3pt]{caption}
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/135441/121799
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\alph{subfigure}}
\usepackage{tikz}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\DeclareCaptionFormat{Sebastiano}{%#1#2\par
{\tikz[remember picture,baseline=-0.5ex]{%
\node[fill=green!80!black,text=white,font=\bfseries\sffamily\large,rounded
corners=0.2em,minimum width=1.8em,minimum height=1.8em](M){#1};
\draw[very thick,green!80!black] (M.west) -- ++ (-1,0);}}%
\hfill\hfill{\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\coordinate(R);
\draw[very thick,green!80!black] (M.east) -- (M.east-|R);
}}\par
#3} 
\captionsetup[sub]{format=Sebastiano}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\linewidth}
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
 \caption{\label{subfig:WorldLine}}
\end{subfigure}\quad%
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\linewidth}
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
 \caption{\label{subfig:LightCone}}
\end{subfigure}     
\caption{Coni di luce. 
\textbf{(a)}~Le linee di universo passanti per l'origine saranno
all'interno del cono. Si vede la linea blu che parte dal punto qui ed ora
rappresentato dal vertice del cono.
\textbf{(b)}~Linee di universo non ammesse nella teoria della
relativit\`a ristretta sono quelle che escono dal cono di luce; ad esempio la
linea \textbf{(1)} esce dal cono che pertanto non sar\`a ammessa; la velocit\`a
nel punto $A$ della linea \textbf{(2)} \`e minore di quella della luce; la linea
arancione \textbf{(3)} rappresenta un viaggiatore dello spazio-tempo con il dono
dell'ubiquit\`a; la linea \textbf{(4)} rappresenta un viaggio indietro nel tempo
a una velocit\`a maggiore di quella della luce.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

How can I add the vertical braces as this screenshot at the start and the end of the `caption`

[image]

and considering that my images of my book are all rectangular `.pdf`, how can I insert images in a rounded rectangle? See, as example, the figure below.

[image]

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: For the second part have a look at tcolorbox (it has means to include a boxed pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book} 
\usepackage{newtxtext}
%%\usepackage{classico}%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{caption}
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/135441/121799
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\alph{subfigure}}
\usepackage{tikz}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\DeclareCaptionFormat{Sebastiano}{%#1#2\par
{\tikz[remember picture,baseline=-0.5ex]{%
\node[fill=green!80!black,text=white,font=\bfseries\sffamily\large,rounded
corners=0.2em,minimum width=1.8em,minimum height=1.8em](M){#1};
\draw[very thick,green!80!black] (M.west) -- ++ (-1,0);}}%
\hfill\hfill{\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\coordinate(R);
\draw[very thick,green!80!black] (M.east) -- (M.east-|R);
}}\par
#3} 
\DeclareCaptionFormat{Incredibile}{%#1#2\par
{\tikz{%
\node[text width=\linewidth-4pt,outer xsep=1.6pt,align=justify](MI){\textbf{\sffamily#1#2}#3};
\draw[very thick,cyan] (MI.north west) -- (MI.south west)
(MI.north east) -- (MI.south east);
}}\par
} 
\captionsetup{format=Incredibile}
\captionsetup[sub]{format=Sebastiano}
\newcommand{\IncludeClippedGraphics}[2][]{\begin{tikzpicture} 
 \node[rounded corners=5pt,clip,preaction={draw=blue,thick},inner sep=-2pt]{%
 \includegraphics[#1]{#2}}; 
 \end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\linewidth}
 \centering
 \IncludeClippedGraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
 \caption{\label{subfig:WorldLine}}
\end{subfigure}\quad%
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\linewidth}
 \centering
 \IncludeClippedGraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
 \caption{\label{subfig:LightCone}}
\end{subfigure}     
\caption{Coni di luce. 
\textbf{(a)}~Le linee di universo passanti per l'origine saranno
all'interno del cono. Si vede la linea blu che parte dal punto qui ed ora
rappresentato dal vertice del cono.
\textbf{(b)}~Linee di universo non ammesse nella teoria della
relativit\`a ristretta sono quelle che escono dal cono di luce; ad esempio la
linea \textbf{(1)} esce dal cono che pertanto non sar\`a ammessa; la velocit\`a
nel punto $A$ della linea \textbf{(2)} \`e minore di quella della luce; la linea
arancione \textbf{(3)} rappresenta un viaggiatore dello spazio-tempo con il dono
dell'ubiquit\`a; la linea \textbf{(4)} rappresenta un viaggio indietro nel tempo
a una velocit\`a maggiore di quella della luce.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: MILLE GRAZIEEEEEEE!!!!! Thank you very much. APPROVED :-).